# Как правильно работать с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, которые размещены в контейнере с `overflow: scroll;`

У блоках при наведении, справа появляется крестик. Все хорошо работает, пока не начинается скролл контейнера

Как прикрепить крестик к блоку?

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.block {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #adadad;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 328px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.block:hover .close {
  right: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="block">
    text
    <div class="close">X</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="block">
    text
    <div class="close">X</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: если у родителя нет position relative то тогда будет позиционироватся от body иначе от родителя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.block {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #adadad;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 100%;
  right: 328px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.block:hover .close {
  right: 360px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="block">
    text
    <div class="close">X</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="block">
    text
    <div class="close">X</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Что бы close прикреплялся к block, надо чтобы у block стоял position:relative.
Иначе close прикрепляется к container-у который ты скролиш.